# Smart contract returns empty

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have a smart contract as you can see below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

contract Coursetro {
    
   string fName="foo";
   uint age=123;
   
   function setInstructor(string memory _fName, uint _age) public {
       fName = _fName;
       age = _age;
   }
   
   function getInstructor() public view returns (string memory,uint){
       return (fName,age);
   }
   
}
```

I want to call my function from js with web3. I use testrpc. Here is my js code:

```
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))
        
        var CoursetroContract = new web3.eth.Contract([ { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "_fName", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "_age", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "setInstructor", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "getInstructor", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" } ], '0x346dE53Bc9B3a26aeE96f919e471962F5A31d58F');

        web3.eth.getAccounts().then(e => web3.eth.defaultAccount = e[0]);

        CoursetroContract.methods.getInstructor().call((err, result) => console.log(result))
```

Everything looks well on remix but when i try to run this js code on my local it writes console empty things like **p {0: "", 1: "0"}**. But i expect something like **p {0: "foo", 1: "123"}**. Because i initialized data.

Comment: Did you deploy the contract on the node which is running on your localhost?

Comment: yes i did. i deployed my contract on web3 i can see requests on testrpc console.

Comment: How did you initialize the contract?

Comment: I initialized at where i define. Sorry, i edited question.

Comment: Did you use the use different compiler/solidity version while compiling and deploying to local test network by any chance? I change the comipler version to 0.6.0 in remix and the getInstructor does not return anything, but works fine with 0.5.*.